# Parsing RDF (RDFXML) in ruby with rdf gem - not working as expected

Tags: ruby, xml, rdf

I'm new to RDF, but the following seems pretty trivial; I'm just not getting the results I'm expecting. I have an RDF/XML file as follows (it validates in the W3C validator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:ore="http://blah.com"
  xmlns:dms="http://blah.com"
>
  <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://blah.com/data/Manifest">
    <ore:aggregates>
      <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://blah.com/data/something">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://blah.com/data/Sequence"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
      </ore:Aggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>
    <ore:aggregates>
      <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://blah.com/data/somethingElse">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://blah.com/data/Sequence"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
      </ore:Aggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>
  </ore:Aggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I try and parse it using the rdf gem as follows, but it's not printing out the statements/triples:

```
RDF::RDFXML::Reader.open(image_collection_file) do |reader|
  puts reader.to_yaml
  puts reader.inspect
  reader.each_statement do |statement|
    statement.inspect! # nothing here
  end
end
```

Output of reader.to_yaml is:

```
--- !ruby/object:RDF::TriX::Reader 
implementation: !ruby/object:Module {}

input: !ruby/object:File {}

library: :nokogiri
options: 
  :validate: false
  :intern: true
  :canonicalize: false
  :prefixes: {}

xml: !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Document 
  decorators: 
  errors: []

  node_cache: []
```

Output of reader.inspect is:

```
#<RDF::TriX::Reader:0x101832a50 @implementation=RDF::TriX::Reader::Nokogiri, @xml=#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x80c16cd8 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c14b7c name="RDF" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c14690 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c14640 name="Aggregation" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14528 prefix="ore" href="http://blah.com"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c144c4 name="about" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://blah.com/data/Manifest">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c13bdc "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c13b78 name="aggregates" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14528 prefix="ore" href="http://blah.com"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c13628 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c135c4 name="Aggregation" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14528 prefix="ore" href="http://blah.com"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c13470 name="about" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://blah.com/data/something">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c12b88 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c12b24 name="type" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c129bc name="resource" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://blah.com/data/Sequence">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c12a5c "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c12160 name="type" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c11ff8 name="resource" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c12084 "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c1165c "\n    ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c114e0 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c11490 name="aggregates" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14528 prefix="ore" href="http://blah.com"> children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c10f2c "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c10edc name="Aggregation" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14528 prefix="ore" href="http://blah.com"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c10d74 name="about" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://blah.com/data/somethingElse">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c1048c "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c1043c name="type" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c102d4 name="resource" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://blah.com/data/Sequence">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c10374 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80c0fa64 name="type" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80c0f910 name="resource" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x80c14af0 prefix="rdf" href="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> value="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c0f99c "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c0ef74 "\n    ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c0edf8 "\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80c0ec7c "\n">]>]>, @options={:validate=>false, :intern=>true, :canonicalize=>false, :prefixes=>{}}, @library=:nokogiri, @input=#<File:data/test.xml>>
```

Is this the expected behavior? The statement.to_yaml is empty. I just want to get at the data in the RDF (this example is simplified). Does anyone have any comments/insight/URLs to share?

Cheers,
  Vanessa

Comment: You may also like to ask your question on semanticoverflow.com as you are more likely to get it seen by people routinely working with the Semantic Web and libraries like RDF.rb

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're doing the `reader.to_yaml` call or what it's purpose is as I'm not a Ruby programmer.

But looking at your key bit of code where you are trying to output the statement you appear to be missing a `puts` keyword.  The [documentation](https://github.com/gkellogg/rdf-rdfxml#readme) for `RDF::RDFXML` on github has the following example:

```
RDF::RDFXML::Reader.open("./etc/doap.xml") do |reader|
  reader.each_statement do |statement|
    puts statement.inspect
  end
end
```

In your example you've missed out the `puts` keyword before `statement.inspect` - try adding this back in and see if that works